# Array vs Single Object - AngularJS / Javascript (Basic)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a very basic array

```
[
  {
    ticketId: 1,
    name: "John",
  },
  {
    ticketId: 124,
    name: "Ads"
  } 
]
```

I show the data in the select

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li ng-repeat="ticket in tickets">
        <a href="#">{{ticket.ticketId}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But how do I use the data from the selected ticket from another place in my code

like

```
 <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <td>{{???}}</td>
 </tr>
```

Controller

```
   $http.get(ticketAPIBaseUrl + '/tickets/' + customerNumber, 
     {withCredentials: false}).then(response => {
       console.log(response);
       vm.tickets = response.data;
   }, error => {
      console.log(error);
   });
```

Comment: could you please explain your use case?

Comment: The user selects a ticketID somewhere in the page. And I want to show things related to that choice (same object) in another part of the html

Comment: you could create a watch on selected ticketid and whenever it changes you just need to find the corresponding record in tickets array.

Comment: please make an example

Answer (score 1):

You can use to that `filter` like so: 
HTML:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="tick"/>
<table>
     <tr ng-repeat="ticket in tickets | ticketFilter:tick">
       <td>{{ticket.name}}</td>
       <td>{{ticket.ticketId}}</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

JS:

```
 app.filter('ticketFilter', function(){
        return function(data, tick){
            if (!tick) return data;
            var ticketItems = [];
            angular.forEach(data, function(item){
                if(item.ticketId == tick) {
                ticketItems.push(item);
              }
            });

            return ticketItems;
        };
    })
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/q2ixIBCm9tfUW0c2V1BC?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ng-click` directive:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li ng-repeat="ticket in tickets">
        <a ng-click="selected=ticket">{{ticket.ticketId}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then display the `selected` item:

```
<tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <td>{{selected.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

For more information, see [AngularJS ng-click Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick).